# Configuring background labels

Tags: jquery, elessar

I need to changes background labels in [Elessar](http://blog.153.io/Elessar/), does anyone know the parameter to changes the default values?
It's actually showing in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm`, and I only need `HH:mm`.

Comment: Could you show what you have right now?

Comment: if I set the parameter bgLabels: 4, appears the background labels (4 in this case) but with format YYYY-MM-DD HH:SS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 1.7, there's a new `bgMarks` option:

```
bgMarks: {
  count: 0, // number of value labels to write in the background of the bar
  interval: Infinity, // provide instead of count to specify the space between labels
  label: id // string or function to write as the text of a label. functions are called with normalised values.
}
```

For your use case, you'd want (assuming you're using Moment.js):

```
bgMarks: {
  count: 4,
  label: function(val) {
    return moment(val).format('HH:mm');
  }
}
```

Comment: I just would like to add that it seems the API description on the project's GitHub page is incorrect, the actual property name is `bgMark`, not the plural `bgMarks`. You can see by yourself in the source-code at https://github.com/quarterto/Elessar/blob/develop/dist/elessar.js#L506